# JS CSS font color and underline

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to change css for the font.

```
<div id="a" onmouseover="chbg('red','b')" onmouseout="chbg('white','b')">This will change b element</div>
<div id="b">This is element b</div>

<div id="f" onmouseover="chbg('blue','g')" onmouseout="chbg('white','g')">This will change g element</div>
<div id="g">This is element g</div>

<div id="j" onmouseover="chbg('yellow','k')" onmouseout="chbg('white','k')">This will change k element</div>
<div id="k">This is element k</div>
```

As what I understand this used 'chbg' to change background color,

If I want to make the font underline + font color how could I applied to this.

Here is live fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NAuxn/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add additional parameter in your function call. So that it will remain the same style when hover out.

**HTML**

```
 <div id="a" onmouseover="chbg('red','b','underline','white')" onmouseout="chbg('white','b','none','black')">This will change b element</div>
 <div id="b">This is element b</div>

 <div id="f" onmouseover="chbg('blue','g','underline','white')" onmouseout="chbg('white','g','none','black')">This will change g element</div>
 <div id="g">This is element g</div>

 <div id="j" onmouseover="chbg('yellow','k','underline','white')" onmouseout="chbg('white','k','none','black')">This will change k element</div>
 <div id="k">This is element k</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
function chbg(color, id, td, fc) { 
document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = color;
document.getElementById(id).style.textDecoration = td;
document.getElementById(id).style.color = fc;
}
```

In the above code I have used four parameters like `chbg('red','b','underline','white')`. The third one will tell the `text-decoration` style and the fourth one will point which color you want on mouse over.

In the mouseout I have rolled back to the normal style. This is the solution for using your code. I would suggest you to create some class with hover style and apply it on mouseover and remove it on mouseout.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NAuxn/5/)

Answer (score 3):

With this function you can change the font color and the underline:
http://jsfiddle.net/NAuxn/4/

```
function chbg(color, id) {     
  document.getElementById(id).style.color = color;
  document.getElementById(id).style.textDecoration = "underline";                        
}
```

Comment: The problem in your solution is all the time the underline will be visible on normal mode. I mean mouse out.

Comment: now whend he do a mouseover the underline won't be reseted to normal by the mouseout

Comment: If he want to reset the styles after mouseover, why don't use CSS?